# React Native Workflow, handle 429 erros and data

Tags: react-native, redux, axios, react-navigation

im looking for a bit of guideness here, im working on a RN app with redux and everytime i enter a new screen on the app, must likely i have a "callinitialData" function inside my useEffect(), using axios to fetch api data to be dispatch() to the redux state.

Everything works but whenever i jump from screen to screen to fast, sometimes i get a 429 error of to many request, so i just setup the redux-persist hoping that would help reduce the amount of request,in my mind thinking that if my api data is equal to my local data, that request wouldnt be necessary to be made.

However it stays the same so i was thinking what would be the best aproach here, **on login try to fetch all the data at once > store it at asyncstorage and redux, and fetch that on each screen ?**

how would i be able then, if i fetch all the data on login, receive the new data sets from the api in real time?

---

**App functionality -**

1. Edit Profile (img, pass, email, name)
2. Data Forms (requeast X, submit data, edit forms)
3. Chat by contacts / create Group chat

**Code Example**

```
const ChatScreen = ({  auth: { user }, getChatContacts, chat: { contacts }, navigation }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getChatContacts();
  }, []);

  const onChatUser = async (_id, name, roomID) => {
    console.log(_id, name, roomID,  contacts.payload.clone)
    navigation.navigate( "Message", {
      _id, name, chatRoomId: roomID, allUsers: contacts.payload.clone
    });

  }

  const renderItem = ({ item , index }  ) => {
    let userName = "";
    item.users.map((users, index) => {
        let idToCheck = users.toString() !== user._id.toString() ? users : false;

        if (idToCheck) {
         let getOneUser = contacts.payload.clone.find(x => x._id === idToCheck);

          userName += "" + getOneUser.name + ", ";
        }
    })

    return (<TouchableOpacity key={item._id} onPress={() => onChatUser(item._id, item.name, item.roomID)}>
      <View style={styles.chatContainer}>
        <FontAwesome name="user-circle-o" size={50} color="#000000"/>
        <Text style={styles.chatTitle}>{ ((userName).length > 32) ?
            (((userName).substring(0,32-3)) + '...') :
            userName }</Text>
        <FontAwesome name="angle-right" size={25} color="#000000"/>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>)
  };

  return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
            clearButtonMode="always"
            placeholder="Search friend"
            style={styles.chatsearch}
        />

        {contacts ?
          (<FlatList
              data={contacts.payload.allContact}
              renderItem={(item, index) => renderItem(item, index)}
              keyExtractor={item => item.id}
              style={styles.FlatListContainer}
          />) : (<Text style={styles.FlatListContainer}></Text>)
        }

      </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

ChatScreen.propTypes = {
  isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool,
  auth: PropTypes.object,

};

const mapStateProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  chat: state.chat
});

export default  connect(mapStateProps, {getChatContacts} )(ChatScreen);
```

**Redux Action**

```
export const getChatContacts = () => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
        header: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    }
    try  {
        const res = await axios.get(API_LINK +"/users/getChatContacts",);


        dispatch({
            type:  GET_CONTACT_CHAT,
            payload: res.data
        });

    }  catch (err){
        console.log(err)
        dispatch({
            type:  ERROR_FAMILY_PARENT,
            payload: { msg: err.response, status: err.response}
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: It seems to me that you are not adding any dependencies to your `useEffect` hook, not even an empty array.

Comment: probably, please show some code

Comment: @IanVasco no i got an empty array to all useEffect that i use

Comment: @VaibhavVishal i added some code example thats chat screen page, pretty much all other screens follow that logic useEffect( initalGetData ,[]) dispatch to redux handle it by states,